# forward an exact copy of all mail to second archive mail server

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I am setting up an mail server with postfix at the moment, and I am almost done with it. But I need to archive all incoming mails. My first setup was to set the `sender_bcc_maps` parameter and the `recipient_bcc_maps` parameter to an external email address. This sends a copy to the given email address.

But what I really want is a second identical mail server with the same users and the corresponding email addresses. This server should receive a copy of each mail that looks like it was send directly to the second server.

Answer (score 2):

Setup another server and have it receive mail for backup.domain.name. Create all accounts both on the regular server and the backup server. Add individual entries for accounts to the sender and recipient bcc maps.

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_maps
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_maps

/etc/postfix/bcc_maps
account1@example.com  account1@backup.example.com
account2@example.com  account2@backup.example.com
```